# zooming messes up current page of uipagecontrol

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming, uipagecontrol

I have a page control with 2 pages. I allow zooming on both pages also. 
when I am zoomed in on the 2nd page, and I scroll around, the currentPage of the page control goes back to page 1 even though i am still on the 2nd page.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    _pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed how I calculated my page to

```
int page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;
```

as shown here: [Getting the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132993/uiscrollview-getting-the-current-page)

Comment: Hi,
I am trying to accomplish the exact thing, I cannot get the scrollview to work, I posted a question here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476944/uiscrollview-sliding-zooming

Do you have a sample project I can look at?

Thanks.