# UIScrollView, sliding, zooming

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have an app which has a uiscrollview, which in turn has two uiimageviews.
The scrollview works fine in sliding between both imageviews, by making the content size twice the width. like so

```
   [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 2, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
```

Now the client wants the user to be able to zoom into any image in those two images. He does not want another modal view with the selected picture zoomed in, but rather on the same uiscrollview he wants this to happen. Is this doable? or a good Idea?

The problem I am having is that when I implement the zooming logic ( implementing the delegate

```
  UIScrollViewDelegate
```

the moment I set the value of

```
 self.scrollView.zoomScale
```

I end up calling this method

```
 - (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   return [self getCurrentVisibleImage];
 }
```

And with that happening, I end up with the UIscrollview that after zooming back to the normal size of the image, the scrollview simply doesn't slide left or right?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about putting both UIImageViews inside a UIView and makin that UIView the viewForZoomingInScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

Answer was simple, I was manipulating contentsize and not setting it properly. that fixed it.